# Apache 2.2.19 rewritten path repeating

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, windows-server-2003

When rewriting a URL from HTTP to HTTPS, Apache is repeating the matched path multiple times - how can it be stopped?

Eg: URL
`example.com/test/`

Output URL
`example.com/testtesttesttesttesttesttest/`

Rewrite Rules Used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Apache version 2.2.19
Server Windows 2003r2

Comment: After some investigation the rewrite rules are working as expected.

Comment: The rewrite rules haven't been adjusted, so can only give a best guess for how it has happened. Possibly an issue with the associated memory for storing the matched pattern - it is as if the variable for the matched pattern has been appended to by the regex engine. Unfortunately don't know the cause and haven't managed to recreate it since.